# Jest: Create a patch for a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to change a file in a node module which is used by a dependency I'm currently using.

Is there a way I can mock a specific file in `node_modules` so jest uses it instead of the original one?

I tried creating the same path and file in `__mocks__` but it kept using the original file.

Jest Config:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment:    'node',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jestSetup.js'],
  testMatch:          ['**/test/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js'],
  testTimeout:        10000,
  verbose:            true,
  bail:               1,
  clearMocks:         true,
  coverageDirectory:  'coverage',
  resetModules:       true,
  restoreMocks:       true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `__mocks__` directory is adjacent to `node_modules` (your project root). Jest will automatically use the mock.

Here is a minimum setup that works: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-jest-mocks-qejos0?file=/foo.test.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is adjacent to `node_modules`. let's say I want to override `node_modules/foo/bar.js`, I tried adding the same file with the needed changes in `__mocks__/foo/bar.js` and `__mocks__/node_modules/foo/bar.js` but neither worked.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think you can do that. And it doesn't sound right too. Because you are relying on the underlying folder structures of a module. You probably need to re-implement the module to a mock by yourself.

Comment: But is it really necessary? I don't know that's the actual case, but instead of keeping thinking about how to mock a specific file in node_modules, maybe it can be solved by making your code easier to test. And don't forget that you don't need to test how a module works, you only need to focus on your own code.

Comment: If the case is, only some specific APIs need to be mocked, `jest.requireActual` might help. I also updated the codesandbox to mock only the `random` function.